# How to display some stuff in the same page instead of redirecting to another page while clicking the submenu of asp:menu?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, aspmenu

I am using asp:menu. My aspx code is:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu_Library" runat="server">
        </asp:Menu>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I am generating the sub menu items (i.e) the childitems dynamically.. If i click the sub menu items it redirects me to a page which i specify like this in my code behind,

```
MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem();
childItem.NavigateUrl = "OtherPage.aspx";
```

But what i need is when i click on sub menu items, it should display some items in same page..

How to achieve this? Please help me.. It can be either in javascript or code behind.. I don't want it to navigate it to another page instead perform the action in same page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Page link you can use javascript for that and any div you can show or hide in it.

Your Code:

```
MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem();
childItem.NavigateUrl = "OtherPage.aspx";
```

Change with:

```
MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem();
childItem.NavigateUrl = "javascript: return GoToSomeLink('"+ count +"');"; //You can pass parameters also
```

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GoToSomeLink(obj) //if parameters are used use them here also.
{
    var count=parseInt(obj); //use this count varible anywhere in the function
    $(#menuDiv).show(); /any div show or hide
    return false;

}
 </script>
```

Comment: Where should i include this javascript function..?

Comment: in the ASPX page under scripts tags.

Comment: i have included inside aspx.. but its throwing me an script error..return' statement outside of function

Comment: little updates in my answer as the javascript function is returning false means any server request in cancelled here

Comment: childItem.NavigateUrl = "javascript:GoToSomeLink();"; gave me the solution

Comment: how could i pass the argument inside that.. I have tried like "javascript:GoToSomeLink(count);" but i couldn achieve that as it is been placed inside quotes.. It is treating it as a string.. I need that int count to be passed to the javascript function

Comment: Updated the answer ..give a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) jquery methods to load the contents dynamically without refreshing the page.

OR you can just hide the related contents inline and show/hide them using [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.load method as follows

```
var a = this.find(".contentWrap"),
a.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href") + " .ajaxDiv");
```

The idea is this

1. put any css-class to every menu/sub-menu on  which you want to load another page say ajaxMenu.
2. set the url of the menu/sub-menu through you code.
3. create a container div on you mage page with css-class (conetntWrap)
4. create a container div on every page which you want to load say .ajaxDiv. This is important because it will not load the _viewstate to your page.
5. now write a function on document.ready as follow

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () 
   {
       $("a.ajaxMenu").live("click", function (a)
       {
           var a = this.find(".contentWrap"),
           a.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href") + " .ajaxDiv");
        });
    )};
   ```

   **---use classes on asp.net **

   ```
   <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" 
        StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="StaticMenuStyle"
        StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle"
        StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle"
        StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="StaticHoverStyle"
       runat="server">
   </asp:Menu>
   ```

   the above are way to add css classe.

Comment: what is contentWrap? i have not used any class like that.. I need to handle things on clicking the sub menu item..How to do that

Comment: i generating the sub menu dynamically.. so i could not add a css class to it